# AS3 - Remove a section of a string using the character index

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash, indexing, character

I have a string, and I want to remove a specific section from it.
The situation is as follows:

```
var input:String = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
var scrubStart:Number = input.indexOf("br");
var scrubEnd: Number = input.indexOf("la");
var output:String = input.substring(0,scrubStart) + input.substring(scrubEnd,input.length);
```

I have it set up like this because the input text is different every time, and the section I want to remove is in a different place every time, but the content of the section is the same.

The code I have doesn't work, and it returns everything after scrubStart. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: `output` is: _The quick lazy dog._ - what are you looking for?

Comment: It seems that in my attempt to describe my issue, I've managed to find the solution!

Answer (score 5):

Code from your question appears to operate as expected, resulting in:

> The quick lazy dog.

This could be accomplished using string methods of either [`slice`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#slice%28%29) or [`substring`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#substring%28%29).

#### Slice:

```
const input:String = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";

var output:String = input.slice(0, input.indexOf("br")) +
                    input.slice(input.indexOf("la"));
```

#### Substring:

```
const input:String = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";

var output:String = input.substring(0, input.indexOf("br")) +
                    input.substring(input.indexOf("la"));
```

#### Regex:

You could also implement regular expressions; although, by pattern instead of index.

```
const input:String = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";

var pattern:RegExp = /brown.*?the /;
var output:String = input.replace(pattern, "");
```